# Code Igniter POST Variable

Tags: codeigniter, post, variables

I am brand new to Code Igniter but I can't seem to find a way to do this in the documentation,
In normal PHP you can retrieve the contents of the entire POST variable like this

`$_POST = $postedVars`

But I can't seem to find something that does this in the same manner, I've tried

`$arr = $this->input->post;`

and

`$arr = $this->input->post();`

With no luck! Is this possible in CI? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need a form or something that sets the variables
Then, you retrieve them.

> $this->input->post('first_name').

You are missing the name of the variable!

The signup form:

```
echo form_open('CHome/signup');
$data=array('name'=>'first_name', 'id'=>'first_name','size'=>40,'value'=>set_value('first_name'));
echo "<p><label for='first_name'>First Name </label>";
echo form_input($data);
echo form_submit('submit','Make Account');
```

The Model:

```
 function addUser(){
    //you should use $this->input->post('first_name')
            $data=array(
                'first_name'=>db_clean(ucfirst($_POST['first_name'])), //db_clean is a custom func
                'last_name'=>db_clean(ucfirst($_POST['last_name'])),        
                'email'=>db_clean($_POST['email']),            
                'username'=>db_clean($_POST['username']),
                'password'=>db_clean(sha1($_POST['password1'])),            
                'type'=>db_clean('user'),
            );

            $this->db->insert('users',$data);
        }
```

Codeigniter stores sessions in cookies, it's all weird.
I suggest just using PHP's native sessions, such as $_SESSION['first_name']. Make sure to write "session_start();" in your controller/model so you can use sessions!! (usually do it in the constructor)

Answer (score 0):

well firstly you need a form to populate the form fields with variables and a submit button to post the the variables from the form fields

```
     <?php
      $attributes = array('class' => 'form-horizontal', 'id' => 
    'myform',    'role'=>'form');
      echo form_open('Iris/login_in', $attributes); ?>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-10 col-md-offset-1">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class ="col-xs-12">
                        <div class="form-group ">
                            <label for="email" class="text-warning" 
                             >Email Address</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control"
                                   name="email"
                                   placeholder="Your Email Address"
                                  required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class ="col-xs-12">
                        <div class="form-group " >
                            <label for="password" class="text-
                            warning">Password</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-
                             control"    name="password"
                                   placeholder="Your password"
                                   required>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div> 
                </form>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can set your data array to your post array like so.  This is VERY usefull if you have many fields. Just make sure your input field name matches your database field name.

```
$data = $_POST;
```

If you have any additional elements in your post array (submit button, hidden fields, etc.) that will not be going into your database, remove them before running your insert.

```
unset($data['SubmitButton']);
unset($data['HiddenField1']);

$this->db->insert('users',$data);
```