# Delete Data using code igniter not working

Tags: codeigniter

I'm trying to delete data by id but it doesn't work.
I have some code like this.

Controller :

```
public function delete()
{
    if (isset($_GET['del'])) {
        $ii = $this->input->post('id');
        $this->P6_model->delete($ii);
        $this->load->view('p6home');
    }
}
```

Model :

```
public function delete($i)
{
    return $this->db->delete('contacts', array('id' => $i));
}
```

Routes :

```
$route['deldata'] = 'p6/delete';
```

View :

```
                foreach ($contacts as $data) {
            ?>
                <tr>
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$data->id?>"/>
                    <td data-label="Name"><?=$data->name?></td>
                    <td data-label="address"><?=$data->address?></td>
                    <td data-label="phone"><?=$data->phone?></td>
                    <td>
                        <button class="positive ui button">Update</button>
                        <button class="negative ui button" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')" name="del" href="deldata">Delete</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
```

Thanks before.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Code Igniter POST Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232347/code-igniter-post-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must have declared base_url, right? Use that in your link to redirect a page. Also, give the get parameter in the URL itself. POST will not work without a form. This should work for you. 
**View:**

```
<?php 
    foreach ($contacts as $data) {
?>
    <tr>
        <td data-label="Name"><?=$data->name?></td>
        <td data-label="address"><?=$data->address?></td>
        <td data-label="phone"><?=$data->phone?></td>
        <td>
            <button class="positive ui button">Update</button>
            <button class="negative ui button" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')" name="del" href="<?php echo base_url('deldata')."/$data->id"; ?>">Delete</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php
    }
?>
```

**Controller:**

```
public function delete($id)
{
    $this->P6_model->delete($id);
    $this->load->view('p6home');    //instead of loading the view here, try redirecting to a controller function and load the view there.
}
```

Comment: Never perform deletion on a GET request -- this is not best practice.  Whenever you are writing data, you pass the data via `$_POST`.  When you are reading, you use `$_GET`.  While this answer may _work_, it should not be used by anyone.